# How would you create a multi-threaded Android app without using the Thread class?

Tags: java, android

How would you create a multi-threaded Android
app without using the Thread class?

Comment: You wouldn't.  You could use some other library that does threading, but at some point its going to be launching a Thread.

Comment: [Search to learn about the Executors framework.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+executorservice&t=iphone&ia=web)